# Nontrivial applications of pairings

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I was reading the [Wikipedia article about weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) and I was a bit confused by the notion of pairing. It seems like a more general way to put two spaces in duality but I was wondering if there are cases where it is interesting to consider a different pairing than
\begin{align}
X\times X^*&\to \mathbb{F}\\
(x,f)&\mapsto f(x)
\end{align}

(or the scalar product which is the "same thing" by Riesz representation)

**recall** : Given two vector spaces $X, Y$ , a duality pairing between
$X$ and $Y$ is a bilinear map
$_X\langle·, ·\rangle_Y : X × Y → \mathbb{R}$
with the following properties:

(i) for all $x ∈ X\setminus\{0\}$ there exists $y ∈ Y \setminus \{0\}$ such that $_X\langle x, y\rangle_Y = 0$;

(ii) for all $y ∈ Y \setminus \{0\}$ there exists $x ∈ X \setminus \{0\}$ such that $_X\langle x, y\rangle_Y = 0$.

Comment: Really, take any duality in functional analysis.

Comment: @QuantumSpace but I can't think of any usefull one which is not the canonical one

Comment: Are you looking for examples where $X=Y$?

Comment: yes for example. I guess $X\neq Y$ would be fine as well